# Can't use javascript within jpanelmenu

Tags: javascript, jquery, jpanelmenu

I'm trying to use this autocomplete search:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

jQuery(function() {
    var availableTags = [
      "Comedy",
      "Music",
      "Radio"
    ];
    jQuery( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
      source: availableTags
    });
  });

</script>
```

Inside this script:

```
/**
  *
  * jPanelMenu 1.4.1 (http://jpanelmenu.com)
  * By Anthony Colangelo (http://acolangelo.com)
  *
* */

(function($){
    $.jPanelMenu = function(options) {
        if ( typeof(options) == "undefined" || options == null ) { options = {}; };

        var jP = {
            options: $.extend({
                menu: '#menu',
                panel: 'body',
                trigger: '.menu-trigger',
                excludedPanelContent: 'style, script',
                clone: true,
                keepEventHandlers: false,

                direction: 'left',
                openPosition: '250px',
                animated: true,
                closeOnContentClick: true,

                keyboardShortcuts: [
                    {
                        code: 27,
                        open: false,
                        close: true 
                    },
                    {
                        code: 37,
                        open: false,
                        close: true 
                    },
                    {
                        code: 39,
                        open: true,
                        close: true 
                    },
                    {
                        code: 77,
                        open: true,
                        close: true 
                    }
                ],

                duration: 150,
                openDuration: options.duration || 150,
                closeDuration: options.duration || 150,

                easing: 'ease-in-out',
                openEasing: options.easing || 'ease-in-out',
                closeEasing: options.easing || 'ease-in-out',

                before: function(){ },
                beforeOpen: function(){ },
                beforeClose: function(){ },

                after: function(){ },
                afterOpen: function(){ },
                afterClose: function(){ },

                beforeOn: function(){ },
                afterOn: function(){ },

                beforeOff: function(){ },
                afterOff: function(){ }
            },options),

            settings: {
                transitionsSupported:   'WebkitTransition' in document.body.style ||
                                        'MozTransition' in document.body.style ||
                                        'msTransition' in document.body.style ||
                                        'OTransition' in document.body.style ||
                                        'Transition' in document.body.style
                ,
                transformsSupported:    'WebkitTransform' in document.body.style ||
                                        'MozTransform' in document.body.style ||
                                        'msTransform' in document.body.style ||
                                        'OTransform' in document.body.style ||
                                        'Transform' in document.body.style
                ,
                cssPrefix: '',
                panelPosition: 'static',
                positionUnits: 'px'
            },

            menu: '#jPanelMenu-menu',

            panel: '.jPanelMenu-panel',

            timeouts: {},

            clearTimeouts: function() {
                clearTimeout(jP.timeouts.open);
                clearTimeout(jP.timeouts.afterOpen);
                clearTimeout(jP.timeouts.afterClose);
            },

            setPositionUnits: function() {
                var foundUnit = false,
                    allowedUnits = ['%','px','em']
                ;

                for (var unitID = 0; unitID < allowedUnits.length; unitID++) {
                    var unit = allowedUnits[unitID];
                    if ( jP.options.openPosition.toString().substr(-unit.length) == unit )
                    {
                        foundUnit = true;
                        jP.settings.positionUnits = unit;
                    }
                }

                if ( !foundUnit ) { jP.options.openPosition = parseInt(jP.options.openPosition) + jP.settings.positionUnits }
            },

            computePositionStyle: function(open, string) {
                var position = (open)?jP.options.openPosition:'0' + jP.settings.positionUnits;
                var property = {};
                if ( jP.settings.transformsSupported ) {
                    var direction = (open && jP.options.direction == 'right')?'-':'';
                    var translate = 'translate3d(' + direction + position + ',0,0)';
                    var transform = 'transform';

                    if ( string ) {
                        property = '';
                        if ( jP.settings.cssPrefix != '' ) { property = jP.settings.cssPrefix + transform + ':' + translate + ';' }
                        property += transform + ':' + translate + ';';
                    } else {
                        if ( jP.settings.cssPrefix != '' ) {  property[jP.settings.cssPrefix + transform] = translate; }
                        property[transform] = translate;
                    }
                } else {
                    if ( string ) {
                        property = '';
                        property = jP.options.direction + ': ' + position + ';';
                    } else {
                        property[jP.options.direction] = position;
                    }
                }
                return property;
            },

            setCSSPrefix: function() {
                jP.settings.cssPrefix = jP.getCSSPrefix();
            },

            setjPanelMenuStyles: function() {
                var bg = 'background:#fff',
                    htmlBG = $('html').css('background-color'),
                    bodyBG = $('body').css('background-color');

                var backgroundGenerator = function(element){
                    var bgs = [];
                    $.each(['background-color','background-image','background-position','background-repeat','background-attachment','background-size','background-clip'], function(i,value){
                        if( element.css(value) !== '' ) {
                            bgs.push(value+':'+element.css(value));
                        }
                    });
                    return bgs.join(';');
                };

                if ( bodyBG !== 'transparent' && bodyBG !== "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)") {
                    bg = backgroundGenerator($('body'));
                } else if ( htmlBG !== 'transparent' && htmlBG !== "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)") {
                    bg = backgroundGenerator($('html'));
                }

                if ( $('#jPanelMenu-style-master').length == 0 ) {
                    $('body').append('<style id="jPanelMenu-style-master">body{width:100%}.jPanelMenu,body{overflow-x:hidden}#jPanelMenu-menu{display:block;position:fixed;top:0;'+jP.options.direction+':0;height:100%;z-index:-1;overflow-x:hidden;overflow-y:scroll;-webkit-overflow-scrolling:touch}.jPanelMenu-panel{position:static;'+jP.options.direction+':0;top:0;z-index:2;width:100%;min-height:100%;' + bg + ';}</style>');
                }
            },

            setMenuState: function(open) {
                var position = (open)?'open':'closed';
                $(jP.options.panel).attr('data-menu-position', position);
            },

            getMenuState: function() {
                return $(jP.options.panel).attr('data-menu-position');
            },

            menuIsOpen: function() {
                if ( jP.getMenuState() == 'open' ) return true;
                else return false;
            },

            setMenuStyle: function(styles) {
                $(jP.menu).css(styles);
            },

            setPanelStyle: function(styles) {
                $(jP.panel).css(styles);
            },

            showMenu: function() {
                jP.setMenuStyle({
                    display: 'block'
                });
                jP.setMenuStyle({
                    'z-index': '1'
                });
            },

            hideMenu: function() {
                jP.setMenuStyle({
                    'z-index': '-1'
                });
                jP.setMenuStyle({
                    display: 'none'
                });
            },

            enableTransitions: function(duration, easing) {
                var formattedDuration = duration/1000;
                var formattedEasing = jP.getCSSEasingFunction(easing);
                jP.disableTransitions();
                $('body').append('<style id="jPanelMenu-style-transitions">.jPanelMenu-panel{' + jP.settings.cssPrefix + 'transition: all ' + formattedDuration + 's ' + formattedEasing + '; transition: all ' + formattedDuration + 's ' + formattedEasing + ';}</style>');
            },

            disableTransitions: function() {
                $('#jPanelMenu-style-transitions').remove();
            },

            getCSSEasingFunction: function(name) {
                switch ( name )
                {
                    case 'linear':
                        return name;
                        break;

                    case 'ease':
                        return name;
                        break;

                    case 'ease-in':
                        return name;
                        break;

                    case 'ease-out':
                        return name;
                        break;

                    case 'ease-in-out':
                        return name;
                        break;

                    default:
                        return 'ease-in-out';
                        break;
                }
            },

            getJSEasingFunction: function(name) {
                switch ( name )
                {
                    case 'linear':
                        return name;
                        break;

                    default:
                        return 'swing';
                        break;
                }
            },

            getVendorPrefix: function() {
                // Thanks to Lea Verou for this beautiful function. (http://lea.verou.me/2009/02/find-the-vendor-prefix-of-the-current-browser)
                if('result' in arguments.callee) return arguments.callee.result;

                var regex = /^(Moz|Webkit|Khtml|O|ms|Icab)(?=[A-Z])/;

                var someScript = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];

                for(var prop in someScript.style)
                {
                    if(regex.test(prop))
                    {
                        // test is faster than match, so it's better to perform
                        // that on the lot and match only when necessary
                        return arguments.callee.result = prop.match(regex)[0];
                    }

                }

                // Nothing found so far? Webkit does not enumerate over the CSS properties of the style object.
                // However (prop in style) returns the correct value, so we'll have to test for
                // the precence of a specific property
                if('WebkitOpacity' in someScript.style) return arguments.callee.result = 'Webkit';
                if('KhtmlOpacity' in someScript.style) return arguments.callee.result = 'Khtml';

                return arguments.callee.result = '';
            },

            getCSSPrefix: function() {
                var prefix = jP.getVendorPrefix();
                if ( prefix != '' ) { return '-' + prefix.toLowerCase() + '-'; }
                return '';
            },

            openMenu: function(animated) {
                if ( typeof(animated) == "undefined" || animated == null ) { animated = jP.options.animated };

                jP.clearTimeouts();

                jP.options.before();
                jP.options.beforeOpen();

                jP.setMenuState(true);

                jP.showMenu();

                var animationChecks = {
                    none: (!animated)?true:false,
                    transitions: (animated && jP.settings.transitionsSupported)?true:false
                };

                if ( animationChecks.transitions || animationChecks.none ) {
                    if ( animationChecks.none ) jP.disableTransitions();
                    if ( animationChecks.transitions ) jP.enableTransitions(jP.options.openDuration, jP.options.openEasing);

                    var newPanelStyle = jP.computePositionStyle(true);
                    jP.setPanelStyle(newPanelStyle);

                    jP.timeouts.afterOpen = setTimeout(function(){
                        jP.options.after();
                        jP.options.afterOpen();
                        jP.initiateContentClickListeners();
                    }, jP.options.openDuration);
                }
                else {
                    var formattedEasing = jP.getJSEasingFunction(jP.options.openEasing);

                    var animationOptions = {};
                    animationOptions[jP.options.direction] = jP.options.openPosition;
                    $(jP.panel).stop().animate(animationOptions, jP.options.openDuration, formattedEasing, function(){
                        jP.options.after();
                        jP.options.afterOpen();
                        jP.initiateContentClickListeners();
                    });
                }
            },

            closeMenu: function(animated) {
                if ( typeof(animated) == "undefined" || animated == null ) { animated = jP.options.animated };

                jP.clearTimeouts();

                jP.options.before();
                jP.options.beforeClose();

                jP.setMenuState(false);

                var animationChecks = {
                    none: (!animated)?true:false,
                    transitions: (animated && jP.settings.transitionsSupported)?true:false
                };

                if ( animationChecks.transitions || animationChecks.none ) {
                    if ( animationChecks.none ) jP.disableTransitions();
                    if ( animationChecks.transitions ) jP.enableTransitions(jP.options.closeDuration, jP.options.closeEasing);

                    var newPanelStyle = jP.computePositionStyle();
                    jP.setPanelStyle(newPanelStyle);

                    jP.timeouts.afterClose = setTimeout(function(){
                        jP.disableTransitions();

                        jP.hideMenu();
                        jP.options.after();
                        jP.options.afterClose();
                        jP.destroyContentClickListeners();
                    }, jP.options.closeDuration);
                }
                else {
                    var formattedEasing = jP.getJSEasingFunction(jP.options.closeEasing);

                    var animationOptions = {};
                    animationOptions[jP.options.direction] = 0 + jP.settings.positionUnits;
                    $(jP.panel).stop().animate(animationOptions, jP.options.closeDuration, formattedEasing, function(){
                        jP.hideMenu();
                        jP.options.after();
                        jP.options.afterClose();
                        jP.destroyContentClickListeners();
                    });
                }
            },

            triggerMenu: function(animated) {
                if ( jP.menuIsOpen() ) jP.closeMenu(animated);
                else jP.openMenu(animated);
            },

            initiateClickListeners: function() {
                $(document).on('click touchend',jP.options.trigger,function(e){
                    jP.triggerMenu(jP.options.animated); e.preventDefault();
                });
            },

            destroyClickListeners: function() {
                $(document).off('click touchend',jP.options.trigger,null);
            },

            initiateContentClickListeners: function() {
                if ( !jP.options.closeOnContentClick ) return false;

                $(document).on('click touchend',jP.panel,function(e){
                    if ( jP.menuIsOpen() ) jP.closeMenu(jP.options.animated);
                    e.preventDefault();
                });
            },

            destroyContentClickListeners: function() {
                if ( !jP.options.closeOnContentClick ) return false;

                $(document).off('click touchend',jP.panel,null);
            },

            initiateKeyboardListeners: function() {
                var preventKeyListeners = ['input', 'textarea', 'select'];
                $(document).on('keydown',function(e){
                    var target = $(e.target),
                        prevent = false;

                    $.each(preventKeyListeners, function(){
                        if (target.is(this.toString())) {
                            prevent = true;
                        }
                    });

                    if ( prevent ) return true;

                    for ( mapping in jP.options.keyboardShortcuts ) {
                        if ( e.which == jP.options.keyboardShortcuts[mapping].code ) {
                            var key = jP.options.keyboardShortcuts[mapping];

                            if ( key.open && key.close ) { jP.triggerMenu(jP.options.animated); }
                            else if ( (key.open && !key.close) && !jP.menuIsOpen() ) { jP.openMenu(jP.options.animated); }
                            else if ( (!key.open && key.close) && jP.menuIsOpen() ) { jP.closeMenu(jP.options.animated); }

                            e.preventDefault();
                        }
                    }
                });
            },

            destroyKeyboardListeners: function() {
                $(document).off('keydown',null);
            },

            setupMarkup: function() {
                $('html').addClass('jPanelMenu');
                $(jP.options.panel + ' > *').not(jP.menu + ', ' + jP.options.excludedPanelContent).wrapAll('<div class="' + jP.panel.replace('.','') + '"/>');
                var menu = ( jP.options.clone )?$(jP.options.menu).clone(jP.options.keepEventHandlers):$(jP.options.menu);
                menu.attr('id', jP.menu.replace('#','')).insertAfter(jP.options.panel + ' > ' + jP.panel);
            },

            resetMarkup: function() {
                $('html').removeClass('jPanelMenu');
                $(jP.options.panel + ' > ' + jP.panel + ' > *').unwrap();
                $(jP.menu).remove();
            },

            init: function() {
                jP.options.beforeOn();

                jP.setPositionUnits();
                jP.setCSSPrefix();
                jP.initiateClickListeners();
                if ( Object.prototype.toString.call(jP.options.keyboardShortcuts) === '[object Array]' ) { jP.initiateKeyboardListeners(); }

                jP.setjPanelMenuStyles();
                jP.setMenuState(false);
                jP.setupMarkup();

                jP.setPanelStyle({ position: (( jP.options.animated && jP.settings.panelPosition === 'static' )?'relative':jP.settings.panelPosition) });
                jP.setMenuStyle({ width: jP.options.openPosition });

                jP.closeMenu(false);

                jP.options.afterOn();
            },

            destroy: function() {
                jP.options.beforeOff();

                jP.closeMenu();
                jP.destroyClickListeners();
                if ( Object.prototype.toString.call(jP.options.keyboardShortcuts) === '[object Array]' ) { jP.destroyKeyboardListeners(); }

                jP.resetMarkup();
                var childrenStyles = {};
                childrenStyles[jP.options.direction] = 'auto';

                jP.options.afterOff();
            }
        };

        return {
            on: jP.init,
            off: jP.destroy,
            trigger: jP.triggerMenu,
            open: jP.openMenu,
            close: jP.closeMenu,
            isOpen: jP.menuIsOpen,
            menu: jP.menu,
            getMenu: function() { return $(jP.menu); },
            panel: jP.panel,
            getPanel: function() { return $(jP.panel); },
            setPosition: function(position) {
                if ( typeof(position) == "undefined" || position == null ) {
                    position = jP.options.openPosition
                }
                jP.options.openPosition = position;
                jP.setMenuStyle({ width: jP.options.openPosition });
            }
        };
    };
})(jQuery);

</script>

<script type="text/javascript">

jQuery(function() {
var jPM = jQuery.jPanelMenu();
var jPM = jQuery.jPanelMenu({
    menu: '#menu-selector',
    trigger: '.menu-trigger-selector',
    duration: 300
});
jPM.on();
 })

</script>
```

The HTML looks like

```
<div class="menu-trigger-selector"><img src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-G1THV0EXgLY/VQgWdKfzIvI/AAAAAAAAAJg/_AtOhuTN9JI/s28-no/hamburger-menu-icon.png" alt="Menu Button" title="Menu Button"></div>
<div id="menu-selector" style="display:none;">

<ul class="info">
<li id="about" class="noselect"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
<li id="faq" class="noselect"><a href="#">About</a></li>
<li id="contribute" class="noselect"><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
</ul>

<ul class="login-register">
<li id="login" class="noselect"><a href="#">Login</a></li>
<li id="register" class="noselect"><a href="#">Register</a></li>
</ul>

<div class="ui-widget">
<input id="tags" placeholder="Search"></input>
</div>

<ul class="podcast-list">
    <li>Main1
        <ul class="podcasts">
            <li>Sub</li>
            <li>Sub</li>
            <li>Sub</li>
            <li>Sub</li>
        </ul>
    </li>

</ul>

</div>

<div class="container">
...
</div>
```

Loading resources in this order

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="../jquery.once.js?v=1.2"></script>
<script src="../drupal.js?nmk3bg"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<script src="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

No jquery works at all though. Scripts work fine anywhere in the body, but not inside the side menu. There are no console errors. I've tried 2 other side menus but javascript doesn't work within them either. I need help either fixing this one or finding another one that supports javascript.

Answer (score 0):

I see you use $ to call jQuery. Try this, it may turn out to be helpful.

```
jQuery( document ).ready(function( $ ){
    // Do stuff here
    // For example, initialize jPanel in here
});
```

Let me know how this turns out.